# При отладке не видно данные расположенные в Span<byte>

Tags: c#, unsafe, .net-5

Я написал структуру в которую можно вместить до 2048 байт данных *(для передачи через Pipe)*.

Дело в том, что можно посмотреть данные которые находятся в `buffer.Message.Data`, но при этом данных в `buffer.Bytes` не видно.

Может я что-то не правильно описал в структуре, или же я просто никак не смогу посмотреть эти данные через отладчик, т.к. при попытке формирования строки из `buffer.Bytes`, все хорошо отрабатывает?

минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
public class Program
{
    static readonly byte[] handShakeMessage
        = new byte[] {
            0xE3, 0x81, 0x93,
            0xE3, 0x81, 0x8D,
            0xE3, 0x82, 0x93,
            0xE3, 0x83, 0xAC,
            0xE3, 0x83, 0xB3,
            0xE3, 0x83, 0x80,
            0xE3, 0x83, 0xA9,
            0xE3, 0x83, 0xBC,
            0x2F, 0x31, 0x2E,
            0x30, 0x2E, 0x30
        };

    public static void Main()
    {
        KokinBuffer buffer = new();
        buffer.Message.Data = handShakeMessage.AsSpan();
        buffer.Message.Type = MessageType.HandShake;

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Message.Data));
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Bytes));
    }
}

public enum MessageType
    : uint
{
    Unknown,
    HandShake,
    Update,
    Status,
    Disconnect
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct KokinMessage
{
    public MessageType Type
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (KokinMessage* pData = &this)
            {
                return *(MessageType*)pData;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (KokinMessage* pData = &this)
            {
                MessageType* pType = (MessageType*)pData;
                *pType = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (void* pData = &this)
            {
                return *(int*)((byte*)pData + sizeof(MessageType));
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (void* pData = &this)
            {
                *(int*)((byte*)pData + sizeof(MessageType)) = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public Span<byte> Data
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (void* pData = &this)
            {
                const int offset = sizeof(MessageType) + sizeof(int);
                return new((byte*)pData + offset, KokinBuffer.Size - offset);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (void* pBuffer = &this)
            {
                byte* pData = (byte*)pBuffer;
                const int offset = sizeof(MessageType) + sizeof(uint);
                Span<byte> data = new(pData + offset, KokinBuffer.Size - offset);
                if (!value.TryCopyTo(data))
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                Length = data.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = Size)]
public unsafe struct KokinBuffer
{
    public const int Size = 2048;

    public Span<byte> Bytes
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (KokinBuffer* pBuffer = &this)
            {
                return new(pBuffer, Size);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (KokinBuffer* pBuffer = &this)
            {
                Span<byte> data = new(pBuffer, Size);
                if (!value.TryCopyTo(data))
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ref KokinMessage Message
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (KokinBuffer* pBuffer = &this)
            {
                return ref *((KokinMessage*)pBuffer);
            }
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Zip()
    {
        return Bytes;
    }

    public static implicit operator ReadOnlySpan<byte>(KokinBuffer buffer)
    {
        return buffer.Bytes;
    }

    public static implicit operator KokinBuffer(Span<byte> span)
    {
        return new KokinBuffer { Bytes = span };
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное дело в том, что `buffer` - это значимый тип, и когда отладчик пытается получить экземпляр, он фактически создает новый внутри себя с учетом полей данных и копирует все значимые типы. Но здесь за счет небезопасного кода используется область памяти, выделенная под структуру в `LayoutKind`, но не выделенная под данные.

Видимо отладчику от этого становится плохо и он просто не клонирует байты в свой новый экземпляр этой структуры, при чем если симотреть в само свойство, то данные есть, если же через инспектор смотреть в это же свойство, не упоминаемое в коде, то данных нет. Может быть, это баг студии, я до конца не понял.

В любом случае, в рантайме все прекрасно работает. Могу только сказать, что вы "слегка" перемудрили, но мысль верная, и мне понравился этот хоть и небезопасный, но подход.

Я решил немного упростить код

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyMessage buffer = new();
        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Привет, мир!");
        buffer.Data = message;
        buffer.Type = MessageType.HandShake;

        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<MyMessage>());
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.Type);
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = buffer;
        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Data));
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
    }
}

public enum MessageType
    : uint
{
    Unknown,
    HandShake,
    Update,
    Status,
    Disconnect
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = size)]
public unsafe struct MyMessage
{
    public const int size = 2048;
    public const int dataOffset = sizeof(int) + sizeof(MessageType);

    public MessageType Type;
    private int _length;

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Data
    {
        get => GetSpan(dataOffset, _length);
        set
        {
            value.CopyTo(GetSpan(dataOffset, size - dataOffset));
            _length = value.Length;
        }
    }

    private ReadOnlySpan<byte> Bytes
    {
        get => GetSpan(0, _length + dataOffset);
        set => value.CopyTo(GetSpan(0, size));
    }

    private Span<byte> GetSpan(int offset, int length)
    {
        fixed (MyMessage* src = &this)
        {
            return new((byte*)src + offset, length);
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> AsSpan() 
        => Bytes;

    public static implicit operator ReadOnlySpan<byte>(MyMessage buffer) 
        => buffer.Bytes;

    public static implicit operator MyMessage(ReadOnlySpan<byte> span) 
        => new() { Bytes = span };
}
```

**UPD:** Немного доработал, теперь длина спана, получаемого из неявного преобразования или через `AsSpan()` будет равна длине полезной нагрузки. Это чтобы можно было сразу слать спан в сеть "как есть". При этом поле `_length` содержит длину блока данных, что валидно для формата передачи данных, чтобы принимающий сервер смог прочитать данные так же в эту же структуру. То есть не обзязательно слать ровно 2 килобайта. Правда принимающей стороне придется все-таки смотреть в это поле, потом вычитывать данные согласно указанной длине и только потом закидывать их в структуру. Я думаю, здесь идея должна быто прозрачна. Если я конечно правильно понял назначение этого всего.

Отправить

```cs
myStream.Write(buffer);
```

Получить

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
myStream.Read(bytes, 0, 8);
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
myStream.Read(bytes, 8, length);
MyMessage buffer = bytes;
```

*Скриншот ниже относится к одной из прошлых версий кода, но я его не стал менять, потому что он свою суть показыват верно.*

Вывод в консоль

```
2048
HandShake
29
Привет, мир!
☺§Привет, мир!
```

Если свойство `Bytes` сделать публичным, то можно увидеть следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А вот так может выглядеть управляемая версия, я все-такие ее больше рекомендую, так как она не содержит ограничения в 2 килобайта. И занимает ровно столько памяти, сколько требуется для хранения данных.

```cs
public record MyMessage
{
    private const int headerSize = 8;
    private const int lengthOffset = 4;

    private readonly byte[] _bytes;
    public MessageType Type
    {
        get => (MessageType)BitConverter.ToUInt32(_bytes, 0);
        set => BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(_bytes, (uint)value);
    }

    public int Length => _bytes.Length;

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Data => _bytes.AsSpan(headerSize);

    public MyMessage(MessageType type, ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
    {
        _bytes = new byte[data.Length + headerSize];
        data.CopyTo(_bytes.AsSpan(headerSize));
        Type = type;
        BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(_bytes.AsSpan(lengthOffset), data.Length);
    }

    private MyMessage(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)
    {
        int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes[lengthOffset..]);
        _bytes = new byte[length + headerSize];
        bytes[.._bytes.Length].CopyTo(_bytes);
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> AsSpan()
        => _bytes;

    public static implicit operator ReadOnlySpan<byte>(MyMessage message)
        => message._bytes;

    public static implicit operator MyMessage(ReadOnlySpan<byte> span)
        => new(span);
}
```

Я сделал ее немутабельной, поэтому тестовый код немного изменился

```cs
MyMessage message = new(MessageType.HandShake, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Привет, мир!"));

Console.WriteLine(message);
ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = message;
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Data));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

Вывод в консоль

```cs
MyMessage { Type = HandShake, Length = 29, Data = System.ReadOnlySpan<Byte>[21] }
Привет, мир!
☺§Привет, мир!
```

Приятный бонус `record`, у нее встроенный `.ToString()`, отображающий ее содержимое.

Можно добавить еще производительности с помощью `ArrayPool<byte>` и `Buffer.BlockCopy`, но код станет значительно сложнее, придется адаптироваться к тому, что `ArrayPool` выдает массив не точно того размера, который нужен, и реализовать `IDisposable` с финализатором, чтобы массив точно возвращался в пул, когда сообщение больше не нужно.

Comment: Да, все верно :) слать нужно не ровно 2кб, жаль что в с# нельзя сделать нормальное объединение как на си.

Comment: @こきん что значит "нормальное объединение"?

Comment: Ну, в плане без указания оффсетов, потом покажу.

Comment: @こきん я вообще код сериализации и десереализации структуры в двоичные данные обычно пишу с помощью `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` прямо в поток или из потока с динамической структурой данных. 1) так нет ограничения на размеры 2) не нужен небезопасный код. Плюс оно тоже весьма быстро работает. Но ваш подход хорош, если максимальная длина фрейма данных жестко ограничена небольшим значением.

Comment: @こきん плюс с потоковым чтением можно реализовать машину состояний (алгоритм "конечный автомат") для вычитывания любой сложности стуктур данных из потока на основе управляющих последовательностей типа "тип пакета+длина", при этом сам пакет может быть сложным состоять из мелких частей. Таким образом реализуется протокол передачи данных любой сложности.

Comment: Вот так выглядит структура на си: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y90pA.png

Comment: @こきん Можно и без указания оффсетов, но кода больше получится https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Comment: @こきん а сяшный юнион делается через явные оффсеты LayoutKind.Explicit очень просто, но в шарпе нельзя просто так объявить инлайн-массив данных. Только если смаршаллировать, но там тоже не все так просто. Вообще, как я выше написал, лучше вообще забить, как там структура в памяти живет, а просто написать код сереализации и десереализации в нужный формат данных с использованием самой обычной структуры или POCO класса, тогда и органичение в килобайтах уйдёт.

Comment: Да, ответ хороший, пожалуй я попробую провести тесты с `POCO`, и областью памяти структуры =) Выберу то что больше подойдет.

Comment: @こきん раз уж у вас .NET 5, попробуйте еще `record` пощупать, это по сути немутабельный класс с данными, но имеет свои плюсы.

Comment: @こきん добавил управляемую версию на базе `record`.