# Определить размер байтов входящего сообщения

Tags: c#, tcp, byte, bytearray

Под каждое входящее сообщение на стороне клиента я выделяю массив байтов (буфер) с размером 256.

Необходимо, чтобы размер буфера сообщений (массив байтов) соотносился с размером входящих сообщений.

Вот так выглядит блок кода, в котором обрабатываются входящие со стороны сервера сообщения:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

string answer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Под каждое сообщение я выделяю массив байтов с размером 256. Получается, даже если входящее сообщение гораздо меньше по размеру - в любом случае это сообщение записывается в массив, размер которого равен 256.

В чём проблема?
Проблема в том, что из-за такого подхода у меня нет возможности провести равенство строк.
Например, если сервер отправляет сообщение "connect" - мне было бы достаточно размера массива 7 (так как семь символов).
Однако, из-за того, что я выделяю под каждое сообщение 256 байтов - используется только 7, а остальные остаются нулевыми.

И следовательно, если я попробую сравнить строки:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

string answer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

 if (answer == "connect") 
     {
         //не выполнится
     }
```

Условие не выполнится! Так как "connect" имеет размер 7, а answer в свою очередь 256, то есть фактически 249 это просто пустые нули.

Comment: в stream.Read возвращает количество байт, которое было фактически прочитано. Он может прочитать не более чем передано третьим параметром, либо -1, если поток завершился. Поэтому нужно сделать слайс из буфера bytes.AsSpan(0, bytesRead) и передать уже его в Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Comment: В тему: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257851/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567).

Comment: @Vein и это еще только начало. Все меняется, когда сообщение фрагментируется на 2 и больше пакета в сети. То есть передаешь "привет", а получаешь "п", "ри", "вет". И с точки зрения TCP это нормально.

Comment: @Vein Подскажите, пожалуйста, в вашем примере bytesRead это что? Просто у меня такого нет, немного заблудился

Comment: Вот так пробую (не знаю, как здесь перенос сделать): int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
            string answer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.AsSpan(0, bytesRead)); ///////// выводит ошибку: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'AsSpan' and no accessible extension method 'AsSpan' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found

Comment: @FlaveHardy у вас .NET Framework 4.x? Он устарел. Надо .NET 5. То есть .NET Core 3 или новее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Сразу предупрежу, что в .NET Framework 4.x ниже показанный код работать не будет. Требуется .NET Core 3.1 или новее. Рекомендую .NET 5 или .NET 6.*

#### Протокол приложения

Чтобы принять TCP сообщение, надо знать его размер, и надо передавать его явно, потому что.

- Сообщение может быть длиннее, чем буфер.
- Сообщение может быть фрагментировано и получено по частям.

Что гарантирует TCP:

- Сообщение будет доставлено, если соединение не будет разорвано.
- Фрагменты сообщения будут получены в том же порядке, в котором были отправлены.

От этого и следует отталкиваться. То есть то, что не гарантирует транспортный протокол, должен гарантировать протокол уровня приложения, то есть ваш протокол.

Самый простой протокол, который можно придумать, это

```cs
Length[4] Message[Length]
```

Где `Length` - 4 байта длины сообщения, `Int32`, а `Message`- это массив байт длиной, указанной перед ним. При этом размер буфера чтения и записи в поток может быть любым, как меньше, так и больше, чем длина сообщения.

#### Создание сообщения

Для начала можно создать класс, который будет представлять само сообщение.

```cs
public class TcpMessage
{
    private byte[] _data;

    public int Length => _data.Length;
    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Data => _data;

    public TcpMessage(byte[] data)
    {
        _data = new byte[data.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, _data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    public static TcpMessage FromString(string message)
    {
        return new TcpMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
    }

    public string AsString()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_data);
    }
}
```

Здесь все очень просто. Данный класс всего-лишь предоставляет данные и их длину и гарантирует, что данные не будут никогда изменены после создания сообщения. При этом сообщение поддерживает только один тип данных - байты. Так мы условились выше в описании протокола уровня приложения.

#### Отправка сообщения

Создадим сообщение

```cs
TcpMessage message = TcpMessage.FromString("Привет");
```

Теперь отправим

```cs
byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);
stream.Write(lengthBytes);
stream.Write(message.Data);
```

Сообщение отправлено.

#### Прием сообщения

Чтение заголовка и создание буфера

```cs
byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
stream.Read(lengthBytes);
byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes)];
```

**Упрощенная версия**

```cs
stream.Read(buffer);
```

Это сработает только если сообщение придет всё и сразу. Но как я выше писал - гарантии нет.

**Полная версия**

```cs
int offset = 0;
while (offset < buffer.Length)
{
    offset += stream.Read(buffer.AsSpan()[offset..]);
}
```

Вот так можно получить текст из буфера

```cs
TcpMessage message = new TcpMessage(buffer);
string text = message.AsString();
```

---

Теперь весь код приема можно засунуть в бесконечный цикл и получится нормальный процесс приема пакетов из потока.