# C# Как правильно возвратить базовый класс при ошибке в создании производного класса

Tags: c#, наследование

Пусть есть следующая структура классов:

```
class Person
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
class Employee : Person
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public Employee(string name, string company): base(name)
    {
        Company = company;
    }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public Student(string name, string group) : base(name)
    {
        Group = group;
    }
}

class Developer : Person
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public Developer(string name, string language) : base(name)
    {
        Language = language;
    }
}
```

Решение о создании того или иного экземпляра принимается в классе фабрике:

```
static class Factory
{
    static Person GetPerson(byte[] bytes, string name, string seconParam)
    {
        switch (bytes[0])
        {
            case 0: return new Employee(name, seconParam);
            case 1: return new Student(name, seconParam);
            case 2: return new Developer(name, seconParam);
            default: return new Person(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Но при возникновении ошибки при создании конкретного экземпляра я ничего не получаю. (этот пример сильно упрощён) Хотелось бы при возникновении ошибки при создании производного класса получить базовый. На ум пришло такое решение:

```
static class Factory2
{
    static Person GetPerson(byte[] bytes, string name, string seconParam)
    {
        switch (bytes[0])
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new Employee(name, seconParam);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return new Person(name);
                    }
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new Student(name, seconParam);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return new Person(name);
                    }
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new Developer(name, seconParam);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return new Person(name);
                    }
                }
            default: return new Person(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать проще и без повторов кода?

UPDATE1:
Это реальные классы дескрипторов :

```
public class Descriptor
{

    public byte DescriptorTag { get; internal set; }

    public byte DescriptorLength { get; internal set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; internal set; }


    public virtual string Name => DescriptorDictionaries.DescriptorNames[DescriptorTag];
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Tag: 0x{DescriptorTag:X2}, {Name}, Length: {DescriptorLength}";
    }

    public Descriptor(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)
    {
        int pointer = 0;
        DescriptorTag = bytes[pointer++];            
        DescriptorLength = bytes[pointer++];            
        if (bytes.Length - pointer >= DescriptorLength)
        {
            Data = bytes.Slice(pointer - 2, DescriptorLength + 2).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Send(LogStatus.Warning, $"Pointer out of descriptor");
        }
    }
    
}

public class BouquetNameDescriptor : Descriptor
{
    public string BouquetName { get; }
    public BouquetNameDescriptor(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes) : base(bytes)
    {
        BouquetName = Utils.BytesToString(bytes.Slice(2, DescriptorLength));
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Bouquet name: {BouquetName}";
    }
}
public class LogicalChannelNumber : Descriptor
{
    public class LcnItem
    {
        public ushort ServiceID { get; internal set; }
        public bool VisisbleServiceDlag { get; internal set; }
        public ushort LogicalChannelNumber { get; internal set; }
    }

    public List<LcnItem> LcnItems { get; internal set; }
    public LogicalChannelNumber(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes) : base(bytes)
    {
        var pointer = 2;
        LcnItems = new List<LcnItem>();
        while (pointer < DescriptorLength)
        {
            var item = new LcnItem();
            item.ServiceID = (ushort)((bytes[pointer++] << 8) + bytes[pointer++]);                
            item.VisisbleServiceDlag = ((bytes[pointer] & 0x80) >> 7) != 0;
            item.LogicalChannelNumber = (ushort)(((bytes[pointer++] & 0x03) << 8) + bytes[pointer++]);                
            LcnItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = "";
        foreach (var item in LcnItems)
        {
            str += $"Service id:{item.ServiceID}, visible:{item.VisisbleServiceDlag}, lcn: {item.LogicalChannelNumber} \n";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Дескрипторы могут быть разной длины. Длину можно узнать только из самого дескриптора. Если в какой-то момент пришёл User defined дескриптор у которого неизвестна его структура и он оказался у примеру очень короткий ( а у нас уже определён дескриптор с таким тегом) , то мы словим исключение при попытке обратится к несуществующему элементу массива или что-то подобное. В таком случае нам нужно извлечь из входных данных базовый дескриптор у которого есть всего 2 поля, но они 100% есть, так как прописаны в стандарте.
По длине дескриптора мы верно определим начало следующего дескриптора. Собственно сможем разобрать всю таблицу корректно.

Comment: Сделать можно, но зачем вам создавать базовый класс, и почему фабрика - это один статический метод? У фабрики по идее должно быть больше обязанностей, чем просто вызвать `new`. И какие например ошибки вы ожидаете? Какую задачу решает массив `byte[]` и почему именно массив?

Comment: Можете весь `switch` обернуть в `try-catch` для начала, вместо каждой ветки в отдельности )

Comment: @CrazyElf в показанном коде нет причин для возникновения исключения. Давайте сначала узнаем у автора, как это вообще должно работать и какую задачу он решает. А пока - это XY-проблема, типа автор спрашивает, как забивать микроскопом, хочется посоветовать молоток, но для начала надо узнать - а что именно надо забивать.

Comment: `этот пример сильно упрощён` сильно усложните его обратно. Суть проблемы явно утеряна.

Comment: @aepot это абстрактный пример. По факту это фабрика для дескрипторов DVB. Решение о создании того или иного класса принимается как раз по 0 байту входного массива. Это так называемый descriptor tag. В интервале 0x00 - 0xFF есть User defined дескрипторы. С ними-то основная проблема и есть. Одна компания решила что 0x88 это один тип, другая компания, что это другой тип. Причём описания части этих дескрипторов не найти. И парсить их нужно по разному. Сейчас в таком случае у меня выходит ошибка. Я бы хотел чтобы возвращался самый базовый тип. Там только два поля, tag и длинна дескриптора.

Comment: Вот и перепишите вопрос так, чтобы то что вы только что написали из него стало понятно, а не абстрактный код. В данном конкретном случае ваша проблема не отслеживается, а задача выглядит странно. Я проблему уловил, вам нужно выбрать тип контейнера для данных по числовому идентификатору, но пока непонятно одно - почему вы втыкаетесь в исключение? Неверные входные данные? И как создание базового класса вам поможет решить проблему? Почему бы не вернуть просто `null` и выдать ошибку десереализации пакета, либо вообще бросить соответствующее исключение? Что вы собираетесь делать с базовым типом?

Comment: В конструктор типа вы передаете исходный массив байт и больше ничего же, верно? А тип, если ему удалось распарсить пакет, создает себя, если не удалось - бросает исключение? Вот так в примере и напишите код, полностью сохранив вашу оригинальную логику. А я уже смогу тогда придумать решение. Просто если я попытаюсь написать решение сейчас, оно будет никак не связано с кодом из вопроса, а это будет выглядеть странно. Отредактируйте вопрос. Одной базы и пары наследников хватит, главное - настоящая логика.

Comment: @aepot добавил. Update1.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно.

Comment: Длина дескриптьоа максимум 256 байт, верно? Пример с разбором пишу.

Comment: @aepot, да максимум 0xFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень короткий ответ:

```cs
static class Factory
{
    static Person GetPerson(byte[] bytes, string name, string seconParam)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (bytes[0])
            {
                case 0: return new Employee(name, seconParam);
                case 1: return new Student(name, seconParam);
                case 2: return new Developer(name, seconParam);
                default: return new Person(name);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Person(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Я по-всякому пытался подъехать к вашему решению, но мне не хватило информации или некоторые способы сильно влияли на процесс десереализации данных.

В частности `unsafe struct` размером 256 байт и `ref readonly struct`, из минусов - нет наследования, из плюсов, один и тот же участок памяти можно переиспользовать на всем процессе десереализации (менять тип стурктуры "на лету"), что сильно ускорит процесс считывания данных. Так же, структуры константного размера (256 байт) можно собрать в пул и переиспользовать, или вообще увести часть аллокаций в стек, то есть свести выделения памяти при чтении потока данных к нулю. От прелестей ООП конечно при такой работе с памятью пришлось бы частично отказаться. Но это уже другая длинная история. И если вас полностью устраивает текущая производительность приложения - то этим всем можно пока пренебречь. Идею можно подсмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257851/373567).

---

Есть несколько советов.

```cs
public class LcnItem
```

Вынесите за пределы класса дескриптора, не создавайте публичные вложенные типы. Если вам действительно нужен тип только для использования внутри какого-то конкретного класса, вложите и сделайте его приватным.

Ну и конструктор `LogicalChannelNumber` я бы как-то так реализовал

```cs
public LcnItem[] LcnItems { get; }

public LogicalChannelsDescriptor(byte[] bytes) : base(bytes)
{
    LcnItems = new LcnItem[DescriptorLength / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < LcnItems.Length; i++)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = bytes.AsSpan()[(2 + i * 4)..];
        LcnItems[i] = new LcnItem()
        {
            ServiceID = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16LittleEndian(span),
            VisisbleServiceDlag = (span[2] & 0x80) != 0,
            LogicalChannelNumber = (ushort)(BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16LittleEndian(span[2..]) & 0x03ff)
        };
    }
}
```

Не стоит использовать список там, где заранее известно количество элементов.

`internal set` для свойств, которые назначаются в конструкторе, вам тоже ни к чему. Если же вам нужны свойства базового класса, которые могут быть изменены только в наследниках, используйте `protected`, а не `internal`.

И последнее, вот есть у вас класс `Descriptor`, и у него есть `DescriptorLength`. Не стоит повторять идно и то же слово при обращении к переменной, ведь если вы переименуете в `Length`, то вместо `descriptor.DescriptorLength` получится `descriptor.Length` - коротко и ясно. Так код будет легче читать.

Comment: Вы меня очень заинтересовали переводом проекта на структуры. Весь день сегодня об этом думал. Хотел бы этим заняться на досуге и выложить готовую либу на GitHub. Подскажите, не встречали ли вы какой-нибудь хороший проект на .net 5+  на GitHub в котором используются именно read only структуры?

Comment: @Deim нет, не встречал. Все что есть - по ссылке. Там по идее никаких космических технологий нет.