# C# Десериализация структуры с наложением полей

Tags: c#, struct

Необходимо выполнить десериализацию структуры которая формально описывается так(порядок big-endian):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Под это написал структуру:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 188)]
public struct testB
{        
    byte b0;        
    byte b1;        
    byte b2;        
    byte b3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 184)]
    public byte[] data;

    public byte Sync { get { return b0; } }
    public bool Tei { get { return ((b1 & 0x80) != 0); } }
    public bool Pusi { get { return ((b1 & 0x40) != 0); } }
    public bool TrPriority { get { return ((b1 & 0x20) != 0); } }
    public ushort Pid { get { return ((ushort)((b1 & 0x1F) << 8 | b2)); } }
    public byte TrScrControl { get { return (byte)((b3 & 0xC0) >> 6); } }
    public byte AdapFControl { get { return (byte)((b3 & 0x30) >> 4); } }
    public byte CC { get { return (byte)(b3 & 0x0F); } }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Sync: 0x{Sync:X}, TEI: {Tei}, PUSI: {Pusi}, Ts priority: {TrPriority}, pid: {Pid}";
    }

}
```

Вызываю так:

```
byte[] tspacket = new byte[] { 0x47, 0x11, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x60, 0x2C, 0x17, 0xD2,
            0x9A, 0x8F, 0x7A, 0xB4, 0x71, 0x89, 0xA6, 0x3F, 0x1E, 0x80, 0x22, 0xDF,
            0x12, 0x95, 0x6C, 0x28, 0x86, 0x15, 0x45, 0x46, 0x2C, 0x2C, 0x07, 0x85,
            0x4D, 0x32, 0xA3, 0xDD, 0xEC, 0x63, 0xAE, 0x5C, 0x2C, 0x50, 0x90, 0xBE,
            0xB9, 0xED, 0x73, 0x8B, 0xFF, 0x14, 0xCE, 0xE1, 0x3D, 0x54, 0x3A, 0x9C,
            0x36, 0x1A, 0xE8, 0xC7, 0xA6, 0xA3, 0x4D, 0x2C, 0x0B, 0x38, 0x80, 0x95,
            0xAD, 0x90, 0xFB, 0x64, 0x73, 0xA8, 0x01, 0x0C, 0xD7, 0x3D, 0x6C, 0x27,
            0xA0, 0xEC, 0xB1, 0x33, 0x90, 0x32, 0xE5, 0x99, 0x85, 0x15, 0xE8, 0x66,
            0xAA, 0x88, 0x81, 0xB7, 0x04, 0x10, 0x7A, 0xB4, 0x2E, 0x76, 0x00, 0x60,
            0xAD, 0xCB, 0x5E, 0x8A, 0x07, 0xA7, 0x17, 0xE4, 0x89, 0x28, 0x99, 0x76,
            0x60, 0xAD, 0xC4, 0x3A, 0x0C, 0x6C, 0xC6, 0x91, 0x5D, 0xB7, 0xD1, 0xE8,
            0xE8, 0xC8, 0xBF, 0xBE, 0xA8, 0xA6, 0xBD, 0x6F, 0x32, 0x25, 0xB7, 0x1E,
            0xB3, 0xAF, 0x6B, 0xC2, 0x5B, 0xE5, 0x89, 0xD4, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x6E, 0x54,
            0x6B, 0xC3, 0x26, 0x55, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0xD1, 0x7F, 0x46, 0xEE, 0x2A, 0x7E,
            0x2D, 0x8E, 0x7E, 0x66, 0x80, 0x74, 0x93, 0x41, 0xEC, 0xCB, 0x2A, 0x80,
            0x82, 0x7C, 0xD7, 0x07, 0xA8, 0xDE, 0x9B, 0x11, 0x72, 0xD8, 0x4A, 0xB8 };

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tspacket, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        testB test = (testB)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(testB));

        handle.Free();

        Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Десериализация выполняется. Но мне хотелось бы чтобы можно было сразу считывать в переменные которые занимают несколько смежных байтов и считывать несколько булевых переменных из одного байта. Примерно в такую структуру:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 188)]    
public struct testA
{
    
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Sync;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public bool Tei;//TODO: bitwise return
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public bool Pusi;//TODO: bitwise return
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public bool TrPriority;//TODO: bitwise return
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public ushort Pid;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte TrScrControl;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte AdapFControl;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte CC;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte[] Data;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Sync: 0x{Sync:X}, TEI: {Tei}, PUSI: {Pusi}, Ts priority: {TrPriority}, pid: {Pid}";
    }
}
```

Этот вариант не компилируется, похоже что проблема с выравниванием. Если адрес начала массива делать кратным 8, то получаю ошибку `System.AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."`

Как правильно десериализовать этот транспортный пакет?

Comment: `Этот вариант не компилируется`, что-то не сходится у меня картина, так как `AccessViolationException` - это ошибка времени выполнения, а не компиляции.

Comment: `public byte[] Data;` вот из-за этого ошибка. Потому что массив - ссылочный тип. А вв наверое думаете, что он прямо а структуре будет лежать. Поэтому данные надо либо смаршалировать, либо использовать [fixed buffers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#fixed-size-buffers) и соответственно, `unsafe` код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одном байте может быть только одна булева переменная. Вы наверное хотите битовые флаги читать?

К примеру у вас есть один байт

```
public byte flags;
```

Пусть будет к примеру `flags & 0x20` это `Flag20`, `flags & 0x40` это `Flag40`.

Тогда вам проще всего завести перечисление.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags : byte
{
    None = 0,
    Flag20 = 0x20,
    Flag40 = 0x40
}
```

И просто заменить тип поля в структуре

```
public MyFlags flags;
```

А переменную можно получить так

```
bool f20 = data.flags.HasFlag(MyFlags.Flag20);
```

Или сразу в условие

```
if (data.flags.HasFlag(MyFlags.Flag20)) { ... }
```

---

Еще судя по исходной структуре вместо 4 байт я бы предолжил использовать один `int` или `uint`, и все флаги сложить в одно перечисление такого типа.

Еще есть пример здесь:

- [При отладке не видно данные расположенные в Span<byte>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257805/373567)

Comment: uint/int считывают в little endian. Нужно дополнительно переворачивать данные. В байтах считывать легче в этом плане. Нет ли какого-нибудь трюка который бы позволил получить прямой порядок байт?

Comment: @Deim если вам нужны флаги - зачем переворачивать? Просто грубо говоря например для байта 0x01 превращается в 0x80 и наоборот. Если для вас удобство важнее, чем производительность, то есть `BitConverter` или `BinaryPrimitives` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives. Но в любом случае флаги и побайтово прокатят.

Comment: С флагами понятно. Спасибо за подсказку. У меня вопрос. Если я сделал флаг типа uint. Булевые переменные я с помощью них вытащу. А как быть с переменными типа byte? Приводить флаг к uint и делать битовые операции с этим числом? В этом конкретном примере второй байт заголовка состоит из 3 флагов и 5 первых бит значения pid. 
У себя в примере я так и сделал. Это в принципе работает, но я не уверен что так делать правильно.

Comment: @Deim `Приводить флаг к uint и делать битовые операции с этим числом?` - именно так. `((uint)flags) & xx >> y`. То есть 2 битовые операции на значение максимум. Каст здесь в плане производительности ничего не стоит, флаги - это и так число, так как это просто указание компилятору, что вы хотите с ними как с числом работать. Можете завести свойство типа `private uint header => (uint)flags;` или наоборот `uint` в флаги преобразовывать через свойство, как удобнее.

Comment: @Deim кстати использовать именно `uint` не факт что удобно, можно `byte+ushort+byte` например. Вижу что данные между ними не пересекаются. В общем, ваш подход в целом правильный, речь только об удобстве и минимизации количества преобразований.